# Winforms Listbox databinding to list of files in a directory

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox

I want to bind a list of files in a directory to a list box.

Here is a code snippet of want i tried so far, lstFiles is a ListBox, I want to bind the Files property to. But the ListBox is empty. Please help.

```
    public partial class Form1 : Form, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private IList<FileInfo> _files = new List<FileInfo>();
        public IList<FileInfo> Files
        {
            get
            {
                return this._files;
            }
            set
            {
                if (value != this._files)
                {
                    this._files = value;
                    NotifyPropertyChanged("Files");
                }
            }
        }
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            lstFiles.DataSource = Files;
            lstFiles.DataBindings.Add("Name", Files, "Files");
            lstFiles.DisplayMember = "Name";
        }

        private void btnStartPath_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var dialog = new FolderBrowserDialog();
            var result = dialog.ShowDialog();
            if (result == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                txtStartPath.Text = dialog.SelectedPath;
            }
        }

        private void btnFind_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Files = new DirectoryInfo(txtStartPath.Text).EnumerateFiles().ToList();
        }

        #region INotifyPropertyChanged Members

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        private void NotifyPropertyChanged(String info)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));
            }
        }
        #endregion
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set the valuemember property. I tried this for example:

```
        IList<FileInfo> myList = new List<FileInfo>();
        FileInfo test1 = new FileInfo(@"G:\test.xls");
        myList.Add(test1);

        listBox1.DisplayMember = "Name";
        listBox1.ValueMember = "FullName";
        listBox1.DataSource = myList;
```

This works as expected :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't see adding files to list in your code,

```
DirectoryInfo dinfo = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\Directory");
```

Files type,

```
_files  = dinfo.GetFiles("*.txt");
```

then

```
foreach( FileInfo file in Files )
{
   listbox1.Items.Add(file.Name);
}
```

Comment: It is a winforms application, user selects a desired path from UI and clicks a Find button to get the list of files. I am using DirectoryInfo(txtStartPath.Text).EnumerateFiles() to get the files added to Files property